AWS elasti cache getting slow when request increases
During the spike, we are noticing our aws serverless elasti cache is slow. Taking 500ms to 2500ms to return data. Normally it returns 2ms-50ms. We find this data using a logging tool and it is placed before and after the function that returns the data from cache. But in dashboard, latency says in microseconds.

